# .Net Core 6 - IIS worker process crashes and needs IIS app restart

Tags: c#, iis, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

```
.NET version: .NET Core 6
Server: Windows Server 2019
IIS: 10
```

I've an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app which crashes randomly (the application fails to respond) and needs an IIS app restart.

Event viewer error description:

> The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Event code: 1026

If the work process fails/aborted, I would like to restart/create a new work process automatically. Any help is highly appreciated.

Application Pool settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You rapid fail setting currently is it will restart after 5 failures in 5 minutes.

You can lower those settings if you like.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/failure

An additional setting might be useful also

Process Orphaning
https://blogs.iis.net/thomad/the-iis-process-model-features

Some errors only happen in a production environment. Killing worker processes ensures up-time but troubleshooting of these errors becomes difficult, e.g. if the failing worker process needs to be debugged. The process orphaning feature in WAS allows worker processes to be recycled without killing the failed worker process. Now a debugger can be attached to it. Additional process orphaning settings allow the execution of a process (e.g. a debugger) if orphaning happens.